# Visual Studio XML Documentation param name value color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xml-documentation

[image]

1) Will someone please tell me the correct term for the XML Documentation param name's value?  I.e. what do I call "iNum1" and "iNum2" on lines 2 and 3 of my code snippet?

2) In Visual Studio, is there any way to get them to stop being the same color as my identifiers?  All my comments are green, except those thingies; they are white (like my identifiers)  :-(

Thank you.
P.S.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Why do those things matter?

Comment: I personally would like to be able to make the Doc Params the same color as the rest of the documentation. It makes it easier for my mind to separate "code" and "documentation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identifiers in the XML Doc Comments are parsed by Visual Studio as the same "type" (if you will) as the identifiers within the code itself.  This makes sense (to me, at least) since that is what they are meant to be.

As such, their color is controlled by the Plain Text item under Fonts and Colors but this is the same item that determines the color of those same identifiers in the code as well so you won't be able to modify the two independently and get the one in the XML Doc Comments to "blend in".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.